# CSS mouse cursor over text in div

Tags: css, mouse-cursor

I want to change the mouse cursor over the text in a certain div.
If I use:

```
.divchange { cursor: pointer;}
```

the cursor will change over the whole div and not just over the text.

Comment: Place the text in a span?

Comment: You need to use the pseudo class :hover

Comment: It doesn´t work by putting the text in a <p> or a <span> probably because the text is created dynamic.

Answer (score 3):

```css
.divchange { 
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;

}
```

```html
<div style="background:gray">
  <div class="divchange">text only</div>
</div>
```

The **point** is `display:inline-block`.

Answer (score 3):

You can place a text in span or you can add hover to the certain text.

Using Hover

```css
.text p:hover {cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

Or just adding style to that element where you want cursor to be a pointer

```css
.text p{cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```